# Rotating Wireframe Sphere in Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'll admit, I'm not quite well-versed in canvas or javascript yet (heck, I haven't done trig in many many years), but I was able to find something similar to what I was looking for in some canvas demos.

Rotating Sphere: http://www.javascriptdemos.com/?demoid=1

It's almost exactly what I wanted, but I was wondering if someone can help me draw lines in rather than it being dotted for longitude and latitude.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To draw a line on an HTML Canvas context:

```
var ctx = mycanvas.getContext('2d');
...
ctx.lineWidth   = 2; //px
ctx.strokeStyle = '#000'; // black
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(14,42); // First point
ctx.lineTo(20,30); // Repeat as desired
ctx.lineTo(25,35); // Repeat as desired
ctx.stroke();      // Actually draw the path!
```

I suspect you're missing the call to `stroke()` in your attempts. Note that you can call `moveTo()` [multiple times during a single path](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/canvas-tutorial/2_2_canvas_moveto.html), as long as you want to use the same lineWidth/strokeStyle for all segments (as it sounds like you do).

Comment: I see in the demo how x, y, and z are mapped out to determine points (where y and z pairs are made to determine the longitudinal segments along a vertical line). However, adding ctx.beginPath() before the first loop and having it loop through ctx.lineTo(z,y) is yielding crazy lines as seen here: http://www.charlietang.net/demo.html